# Laravel migration works on Linux but not on windows

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-migrations

When I try to run my Laravel migration on windows
this is the migration file that fails on Windows but works on Linux.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTenantOwnerBridgeTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Schema table name to migrate
     * @var string
     */
    public $tableName = 'tenant_owner_bridge';

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     * @table tenant_owner_bridge
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create($this->tableName, function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('tenant_owner_id');
            $table->string('tenant_id', 191);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('primary_admin_id');

            $table->index(["primary_admin_id"], 'fk_tenant_owner_bridge_user_id_idx');

            $table->index(["tenant_id"], 'fk_tenant_owner_bridge_tenant_id_idx');

            $table->index(["tenant_owner_id"], 'fk_tenant_owner_bridge_tenant_owner_id_idx');
            $table->nullableTimestamps();


            $table->foreign('tenant_id', 'fk_tenant_owner_bridge_tenant_id_idx')
                ->references('id')->on('tenants')
                ->onDelete('no action')
                ->onUpdate('no action');

            $table->foreign('tenant_owner_id', 'fk_tenant_owner_bridge_tenant_owner_id_idx')
                ->references('id')->on('tenant_owners_info')
                ->onDelete('no action')
                ->onUpdate('no action');

            $table->foreign('primary_admin_id', 'fk_tenant_owner_bridge_user_id_idx')
                ->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onDelete('no action')
                ->onUpdate('no action');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
     public function down()
     {
       Schema::dropIfExists($this->tableName);
     }
}
```

This is the error that is thrown.
**SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `primehybrid`.`tenant_owner_bridge` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `tenant_owner_bridge` add constraint `fk_tenant_owner_bridge_tenant_id_idx` foreign key (`tenant_id`) references `tenants` (`id`) on delete no action on update no action)**

Here is the table that the foreign key references.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateTenantsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('tenants', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id')->primary();

            // your custom columns may go here

            $table->timestamps();
            $table->json('data')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tenants');
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why it works on Linux but not Windows and why it fails on Windows.
Also see my list of migration files:

```
2012_08_06_000003_create_account_statuses_table.php
2013_08_06_000004_create_countries_table.php
**2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php**
2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table.php
2016_06_01_000001_create_oauth_auth_codes_table.php
2016_06_01_000002_create_oauth_access_tokens_table.php
2016_06_01_000003_create_oauth_refresh_tokens_table.php
2016_06_01_000004_create_oauth_clients_table.php
2016_06_01_000005_create_oauth_personal_access_clients_table.php
2018_08_08_100000_create_telescope_entries_table.php
2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table.php
**2019_09_15_000010_create_tenants_table.php**
2019_09_15_000020_create_domains_table.php
2020_04_06_222004_create_sessions_table.php
2020_05_15_000010_create_tenant_user_impersonation_tokens_table.php
2020_08_10_170933_create_jobs_table.php
2021_04_30_174805_create_cache_table.php
**2021_08_06_000000_create_tenant_owners_info_table.php**
2021_08_06_000001_create_secret_questions_table.php
2021_08_06_000006_create_recovery_info_table.php
**2021_08_06_000007_create_tenant_owner_bridge_table.php**
2021_08_06_223928_create_permission_tables.php
```

Comment: Migrations need to be run in the correct order, this is done by filename. If you are having problems between Windows and Linux, case sensitivity is the likely problem. What are the relevant filenames?

Comment: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php
2019_09_15_000010_create_tenants_table.php
2021_08_06_000000_create_tenant_owners_info_table.php
2021_08_06_000007_create_tenant_owner_bridge_table.php

Comment: Note your column definitions don't match between the tables as well.

Comment: try removing `fk_tenant_owner_bridge_tenant_id_idx` in the `foreign` method so it will be like
`$table->foreign('tenant_id')->references('id')->on('tenants')->onDelete('no action')->onUpdate('no action');`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are adding the `index()` method, you can simple create a foreign reference by writing something like

For Laravel > 5.5

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('primary_admin_id');
$table->foreign('primary_admin_id')
             ->references('id')
             ->on('users')
             ->onUpdate('no action')
             ->onDelete('no action');
```

For Laravel 8

```
$table->foreignId('primary_admin_id')->
             ->references('id')
             ->on('users')
             ->onUpdate('no action');
             ->onDelete('no action');
```

Also, you need to keep in mind that your migration should be made in proper order, for example if you have an `item_order` table, you should have all the required tables which will have references **in** the `item_order` table